# ASP.NET Web API 2 primitive type from body (boolean) error

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, webapi2

I have an action

```
[HttpPatch]
public IHttpActionResult foo(int id, [FromBody]bool boolVariable)
{
 return Ok();
}
```

I am still debugging and when I try to send some data with Postman I get a strange error

> "Message": "The request is invalid.",
>       "MessageDetail": "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'boolVariable' of non-nullable type 'System.Boolean' for
>   method 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult foo(Int32,
>   Boolean)' in 'ProjectName.Controllers.NameController'. An optional
>   parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as
>   an optional parameter."

The problem is that it isn't binding boolVariable with my json body... yea I can easily solve the problem with a bind model

```
  public class FooBindModel
    {
        public bool boolVariable{ get; set; }
    }


public IHttpActionResult foo(int id, FooBindModel bindModel)
{
 return Ok();
}
```

However it's bugging me why doesn't it bind the variable from the json's body? I am specifying [FromBody] in the action parameters...

Comment: How do you specify the body when you posting to the api?

Comment: @marcus {"boolVariable":true}

Answer (score 7):

This is actually a case where you really need to use the often misused `[FromBody]` attribute.
Web Api will by default try to read the request body as an object which makes the `[FromBody]` attribute redundant when dealing with objects.

But when you have a value type in your request body then you need to tell Web Api that you want to get your value type from the body and that is what `[FromBody]` does.

So to solve this you should specify the `[FromBody] bool boolVariable` and only send the bool value in the body, i.e

> true

Read more under the [Using [FromBody]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) section